# How to remove redirect chains created because of Google Adsense

Tags: redirect, adsense, pagespeed

I see several redirect chains created because of adsense redirecting to Doubleclick and other ad-platforms. How can such redirect chains be minimized. An example of such a chain is in the snapshot.
[Page Speed analysis suggests these redirects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KF3eZ.png)